# Systemd service to run a script when a USB HDD is plugged in

Tags: systemd, fstab, systemd-mount

I'm trying to run a backup script when a USB HDD is plugged in, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

The backup script is also supposed to unmount (and possibly poweroff) the disk when done.

I have no entries in `/etc/fstab` for that disk. I simply assigned a label (4tb) to it with `e2label` and it will automatically mount to `/media/koichirose/4tb`, owned by koichirose. Everything good so far.

Here's the systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Launches backup script when the 4TB WD drive is plugged in
Requires=media-koichirose-4tb.mount
After=media-koichirose-4tb.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/koichirose/scripts/backup_to_4tb

[Install]
WantedBy=media-koichirose-4tb.mount
```

If I enable this and plug the HDD in, `/media/koichirose/4tb` is created, owned by root, and soon after `/media/koichirose/4tb1` is created, owned by koichirose. The drive is actually mounted on 4tb1 and 4tb is empty. The backup script then runs and fails because it looks for '4tb' and not '4tb1'. If I unmount 4tb1, 4tb is still there, owned by root.

If I disable the service, everything is fine again, the drive is mounted to 4tb and the dir is correctly owned by the user.

How can I fix this?

Bonus question: at the end of my script I'm currently executing `umount`.
This is good but I found out about:

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdc1
udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdc
```

Which would unmount and poweroff the drive.
Two issues with it: it asks for my sudo password (I'd like it to run unattended) and it uses the device name (which could change) instead of the mount point (which I'm trying to make 'static').

Edit: here's the backup script (`/home/koichirose/scripts/backup_to_4tb`):

```
#!/bin/bash

export RESTIC_PASSWORD="mypassword"
repo_path=/media/koichirose/4tb/restic_incoming_backups
dir_to_backup=/home/koichirose

/usr/local/bin/restic -r $repo_path backup $dir_to_backup

#replace with udisksctl later...
umount /media/koichirose/4tb
```

Comment: What mount point are you specifying in your script?

Comment: My script tries to peform a restic backup to a repository in /media/koichirose/4tb

Comment: I can't understand how 4tb1 is even referenced if you haven't specified it in the script. Also udisksctl unmount -b $(df <mountpoint> | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }') and udisksctl power-off -b $(df -h <mountpoint> | tail -1 | awk '{ print substr($1,1,length($1)-1)}') will help you with your bonus question. You will need to look into how to set the command up with passwordless sudo prefix

Comment: I believe something is happening before my backup script is called and systemd creates 4tb. My backup script expects the disk to already be mounted and doesn't do anything to mount it. Thank you for the bonus question answer, I'll look into it once I fix this :)

Comment: Yes but if you only have 4tb set up as a directory with no 4tb1, 4tb1 mount which hasn't even been specified should fail?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, sorry. /media/koichirose is empty when the device is unplugged. Without the systemd service, when I plug the disk in it will create 4tb, owned by me, everything good. With the systemd service it will first create 4tb, owned by root, and then 4tb1, owned by me. Also there's nothing about that disk in /etc/fstab.

Comment: I think we need to see /home/koichirose/scripts/backup_to_4tb

Comment: edited the original post and added the backup script

Comment: Please include the contents of `media-koichirose-4tb.mount`.

Comment: Is that a file? I thought it was just an identifier for the /media/koichirose/4tb dir. Where do I find it? Within /etc/systemd/system there's "media-koichirose-4tb.mount.wants" with a file symlinking the service in /etc/systemd/system/backup_to_4tb.service. This was created automatically when I enabled the service.

Comment: Take out the requires and after mount directives and try it again. I think that this is conflicting with your script.

Comment: Doing so won't start the script when I plug in the HDD drive

Comment: I'm also interested if you find a solution. I'm experiencing the same issue, in the same context. Right now I launch my backup script manually because of this.